# Convert columns of lists to column of dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

In a large pandas Dataframe, I have three columns (`fruit`, `vegetable`, and `first_name`). The values of these columns are lists.

From the lists, I want to create one new column with a list of dictionaries for each row of the DataFrame.

I have three columns (`fruit`, `vegetable`, and `first_name`) with each row having lists as their values.

First row of my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 "fruit": [["Apple", "Banana","Pear","Grape","Pineapple"]],
 "vegetable": [["Celery","Onion","Potato","Broccoli","Sprouts"]],
 "first_name": [["Sam", "Beth", "John", "Daisy", "Jane"]]
})
```

How do I transform the three columns to one column and have the value look like this instead?

```
[
   {"fruit": "Apple", "vegetable":"Celery", "first_name":"Sam"}, 
   {"fruit": "Banana", "vegetable":"Onion", "first_name":"Beth"},
   {"fruit": "Pear", "vegetable":"Potato", "first_name":"John"},
   {"fruit": "Grape", "vegetable":"Broccoli", "first_name":"Daisy"},
   {"fruit": "Pineapple", "vegetable":"Sprouts", "first_name":"Jane"}
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIUC you can do it with (1) `.explode()` and (2) `.to_dict()`

```
df.apply(pd.Series.explode).to_dict(orient='records')
#output:
[{'fruit': 'Apple', 'vegetable': 'Celery', 'first_name': 'Sam'},
 {'fruit': 'Banana', 'vegetable': 'Onion', 'first_name': 'Beth'},
 {'fruit': 'Pear', 'vegetable': 'Potato', 'first_name': 'John'},
 {'fruit': 'Grape', 'vegetable': 'Broccoli', 'first_name': 'Daisy'},
 {'fruit': 'Pineapple', 'vegetable': 'Sprouts', 'first_name': 'Jane'}]
```

Comment: Thanks I used your suggestion in combination with this to get my new column: pd.DataFrame({'party_items':df.apply(pd.Series.explode).to_dict(orient='records')})

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the `explode`d DataFrame using `to_dict` and then calling `pd.DataFrame`. It will be a bit faster for smaller lists, but is essentially the same once you have 10,000+ items.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.iloc[0].to_dict()).to_dict('records')

[{'fruit': 'Apple', 'vegetable': 'Celery', 'first_name': 'Sam'},
 {'fruit': 'Banana', 'vegetable': 'Onion', 'first_name': 'Beth'},
 {'fruit': 'Pear', 'vegetable': 'Potato', 'first_name': 'John'},
 {'fruit': 'Grape', 'vegetable': 'Broccoli', 'first_name': 'Daisy'},
 {'fruit': 'Pineapple', 'vegetable': 'Sprouts', 'first_name': 'Jane'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

the major issue to take care of is to flatten the value for each value in the dictionary. A rather manual implementation is:

```
for i in ["fruit","vegetable","first_name"]:    
        flat_list = [item for sublist in df[i] for item in sublist]    
        list.append(flat_list)
        
        list_of_dic = [] for i in range(5):    
            dic = {}    
            dic["furit"] = list[0][i]    
            dic["vegetable"] = list[1][i]
            dic["first_name"] = list[2][i]
            list_of_dic.append(dic)
```